# TI-89 factor() return value to two variables

Tags: calculator

I am writing a function for my TI-89 Titanium. I see that there is a built-in factor() function under Algebra(F2). I know that in my use case it is going to be the sum of two integers; for example my function might call factor(899) in part of it and expect 29*31. How can I assign these values to two variables? I am going to need to use them later in my program. For example I might want to have q set to 29 and r set to 31.

Comment: Note that this question pushes up against the boundaries of what is in scope for math.se... usually I'd recommend asking this kind of question over at SO but to be honest, I'm not convinced anywhere there is more knowledgeable about programming TI-89s than people here...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; I wasn't quite sure myself. If a majority thinks it is better suited there I'll gladly move it. I was just hoping this would be a quick answer for someone who is more familiar with the TIs than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but I've got around this problem using the string() function.

string(factor(899))="29*31"

Then you can extract the numbers into a list from there.

**EDIT**:To extract just two variables, like in your example isn't too difficult.
If you are in a program, you could first store string(factor(899)) to a variable.  Say string(factor(899))STO>"stringf"

Then:
expr(left(stringf,inString(stringf,"*")-1)) will return 29.  inString() finds the "*" in your string, left() takes the left part of your sting until right before the "*" and expr() converts the string to a number.

Similarly to get the right side of the "*" you could go with expr(right(stringf,length(stringf)-inString(stringf,"*")))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How might I extract them in to a list? Sorry I'm not articulate in TI-BASIC :(

Comment: I gave it a shot.  It's been a long time since I've worked with these TI-Basic functions.